# javascript get value from first objects in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm

there is a sample data:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    stockCount: 12,
    category: "car",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    stockCount: 12,
    category: "car",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    stockCount: 12,
    category: "car",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    stockCount: 12,
    category: "plane",
  },

  {
    id: 5,
    stockCount: 12,
    category: "plane",
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    stockCount: 12,
    category: "plane",
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    stockCount: 12,
    category: "plane",
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    stockCount: 12,
    category: "ship",
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    stockCount: 12,
    category: "ship",
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    stockCount: 12,
    category: "ship",
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    stockCount: 12,
    category: "ship",
  },
];
```

what I want is to get the categories here. when I do this with the .map() function it returns all the categories one by one. but what I want is just to get it in "car", "plane", "ship" format. I don't want copies.
how do i know this?

here my loop code :

```
{DummyProducts.map((item, index) => (
        <Link to="/" className={Style.NavBottomLink}>
          {item.category}
        </Link>
      ))}
```

Comment: filter the array first?

Comment: You can use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) in JavaScript that remove duplicates on its own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can readily do this with a `Set`, which ignores duplicates if you try to add them:

```
const categorySet = new Set();
for (const {category} of DummyProducts) {
    categorySet.add(category);
}
```

or somewhat more concisely:

```
const categorySet = new Set(DummyProducts.map(({category}) => category));
```

If you want that as an array (for `map`), you can use `[...categorySet]`. So for instance, having done the above:

```
{[...categorySet].map(category => (
    <Link to="/" className={Style.NavBottomLink}>
        {category}
    </Link>
))}
```

Or if you want to convert to array immediately:

```
const categorySet = new Set();
for (const {category} of DummyProducts) {
    categorySet.add(category);
}
const categories = [...categorySet];
```

or:

```
const categories = [...new Set(DummyProducts.map(({category}) => category))];
```

Then use it directly:

```
{categories.map(category => (
    <Link to="/" className={Style.NavBottomLink}>
        {category}
    </Link>
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a `Set` as follows:

```
const unique_categories = [...new Set(DummyProducts.map(item => item.category))];
(
    unique_categories.map(category => (
        <Link to="/" className={Style.NavBottomLink}>
              {category}
        </Link>
    )
)
```